# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Graphs'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've created an Azure Function to connect to a CosmosDB Graph. I'm using the nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Graph 0.3.0-preview and am getting the error when I hit the endpoint of the function.

`Exception while executing function: GetTrain -> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Graphs, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The code for the function is below, but it doesn't even get as far as that.

```
[FunctionName("GetThing")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "thing/{id}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string id, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string endpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"];
    string authKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authkey"];
    string db = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"];
    string collection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["collection"];

    DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey,
        new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp });

    DocumentCollection graph = await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(db),
            new DocumentCollection { Id = collection },
            new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });


        IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, $"g.V('{id}').has('thing')");

    // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello");
}
```

## Update

Seems there is a build warning, completely didn't see that. Any thoughts?

> Warning MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Users\blah.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.graphs\0.3.0-preview\lib\net461\Microsoft.Azure.Graphs.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Comment: I also could reproduce it on my side, we could give our [feedback](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues) to azure function team

Comment: Do you have any compile-time warnings?

Comment: Yes, updated with warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the 0.2.4-preview version of the Microsoft.Azure.Graphs package. There seems to be an issue with the 0.3.0 release. See recent comments on the SDK page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-sdk-dotnet

And I added a GitHub issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/361

Comment: I downgraded my package and things started working a lot better than before, now I just need to write better queries!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is resolve for packages [Microsoft.Azure.Graphs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graphs/0.3.1-preview) >= `0.3.1-preview`.

As others have pointed out, the issue was that Microsoft.Azure.Graphs was previously targeting x64 platform only. New versions of the assembly are now compiled targeting AnyCPU (MSIL).

Answer (score 0):

This issue on github fixes everything to me https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/361 only change Any Cpu to x64